# Where is the kernel weight initialization in my CNN model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using a convolutional neural net (CNN) called `make_unet` from [here](https://github.com/SUZhaoyu/keras-semantic-segmentation/blob/develop/src/semseg/models/unet.py). It works and code is able to run with this CNN. But I know that in deep learning you have to initialize weights for optimization of the neural network.

The [documentation](https://keras.io/initializers/) in Keras clearly indicates the use of a `kernel_initializer` for weight initialization. However, I do not see any `kernel_initializer` in the `make_unet` function I am using.

Anyone who can provide some insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Keras initialisers are passed on a per-layer basis via arguments `kernel_initializer` and `bias_initializer`, e.g.

```
Dense(64, kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros')
```

All built-in layers come with a sensible default initialiser. For example, all convolutional layers use `kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'`, `bias_initializer='zeros'`. Keras gives you many [alternative options](https://keras.io/initializers/). You can also create your custom initialisers.

Comment: So does it mean that my CNN is using `glorot_uniform` on the backend?

Comment: @unknown121 from what I've seen in the code you've linked, yes.